# cx_freeze, conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.18, need exactly 8.5.15

Tags: python, tcl, anaconda, tk-toolkit, cx-freeze

It looks like this question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706022/version-conflict-for-package-tk-have-8-5-2-need-exactly-8-5-15) before, but didn't resolve the issue. I'm using cx_freeze for an application, and when I attempt to run it, my output is:

```
{C:\Users\ant\Documents\GitHub\vocal\calipso\build\exe.win32-2.7\tcl} C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/exe.win32-2.7/tcl8.5 C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/library C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/library C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/tcl8.5.18/library C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/tcl8.5.18/library

C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/exe.win32-2.7/tcl/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.18, need exactly 8.5.15
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.18, need exactly 8.5.15
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.5.15"
    (file "C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/exe.win32-2.7/tcl/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Users/ant/Documents/GitHub/vocal/calipso/build/exe.win32-2.7/tcl/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Makes sense, looks like Tcl is the wrong version. But how do I get ahold of 8.5.15? I've looked all over the web and can't seem to find anything to download previous versions of tcl.

I'm on Windows 7, 32 bit anaconda python 2.7 . I don't have a clue of how to resolve this issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666747/tcl-tk-version-in-python-installation `Python:Standart version TCL`, `Python-Module: Require X.X.X TCL`, replace `require TCL version` on your related module.

Comment: @dsgdfg worked for me! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related questions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666747/tcl-tk-version-in-python-installation)

Python :`Standart version TCL`

Python-Module: `Require X.X.X TCL`

**Replace require TCL version on your related module.**